# c++ custom string class failed to output objects inside vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, ostream, chars

I'm trying to implement custom `String` class and I'm failing at console output, I have the following code:

```
class MyString {
public:
    MyString() {
        _length = 0;
        _str = new char[0];
    }
    MyString(const char* c_str) {
        _length = 0;
        if (c_str) {
            while (c_str[_length] != '\0') {
                ++_length;
            }
        }
        _str = new char[_length];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < _length; ++i) {
            _str[i] = c_str[i];
        }
    }
    ~MyString() {
        delete[] _str;
    }
    size_t length() const {
        return _length;
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyString& str) {
        if (str._length > 0) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < str._length; ++i) os << str._str[i];
        } else os << "";
        return os;
    }
private:
    char* _str;
    size_t _length;
};
```

It seems to work okay, but when I use `vector` of such objects I have strange symbols in my output, look (idk how it will be shown at stack, sorry):

```
vector<MyString> my_strings;
my_strings.push_back(MyString("The longest string in the world"));
cout << my_strings.front() << endl;
```

Output: `▄└ ▄est string in the world`

But when I'm just:
`cout << MyString("The longest string in the world") << endl;`

Output: `The longest string in the world`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to follow [The Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: Where is the copy-constructor of your class?